# Get max from value in OrderedDict in Python

Tags: python

(I know there is a lot of similarly questions, but I could not find an question where there are multiple dicts)

I have this OrderedDict where I would like to find the highest default value:

```
print(item['actions'])
#Output:
OrderedDict(
    [('action', 
        [
            OrderedDict(
                [
                    ('name', 'New Subscription'),
                    ('type', 'sale'),
                    ('id', '388899'),
                    ('commission', 
                        OrderedDict(
                            [
                                ('default', '40.00%')
                            ]
                        )
                    )
                ]
            ), 
            OrderedDict(
                [
                    ('name', 'Special Subscription'),
                    ('type', 'sale'),
                    ('id', '849556'),
                    ('commission', 
                        OrderedDict(
                            [
                                ('default', '30.00%'),
                            ]
                        )
                    )
                ]
            )
        ]
    )]
)
```

Tried something like this:

`max(item['actions'], key=lambda k: k['commission']['default'])`

But this clearly not the way to access the 'default' value.

Comment: Apart from the typo `actions` vs. `action`, that works just fine. It returns the first nested `OrderedDict` which has the `40.00%` value. You just need to access *its* `['commission']['default']` value, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: You missed accessing the first `action` key; `max(item['actions']['action'], key=lambda k: k['commission']['default'])`

Comment: @OferSadan: Yes, you are correct! Type an answer, and I'll accept!

Comment: @TomasJacobsen the question is closed so I can't but have fun!

Comment: @deceze just saying, this wasn't a typo after all

Comment: @Ofer You're right, that was a bit subtle and I missed it. Not *really* worth reopening the question for either though.

Comment: @deceze I just thought that was the procedure in this case, your call!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer on behalf of Ofer Sadan:

You missed accessing the first action key; max(item['actions']['action'], key=lambda k: k['commission']['default'])